# How to easily find & link to that amazingly helpful "How to find the positions of the planets and stars?" question with the big Community Wiki answer?

Tags: support, specific-question, community-wiki

There's a question that goes something like:

> How to find the positions of the planets and stars?

but that's not it exactly. One of the very early members of Astronomy SE started a Community Wiki answer which has grown to be an extensive and extremely useful list.

But I keep forgetting how to find this question. The community member is no longer with us, so I can't search by user anymore.

Is there anything that can be done to make this more readily accessible or at least more readily *findable*? It's such a great resource, I think many community members could benefit from knowing some "shortcut" to it.

If I could find it I could check how many times it's been linked to already, the number could/should probably be even higher.

I thought that looking for posts that contain skyfield and stellarium would be enough, but [that search is not finding it](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=skyfield+stellarium) though I am pretty sure the big wiki answer mentions both.

And unfortunately SE prevents us from searching for users no longer here. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21

Help!

---

Here's what I saw today that sent me looking for it

- [looking for a plugin or API for Moon-phases and sky-map](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/47501/7982)

Comment: It is probably easier to find if you click *Ask Question* and enter your search terms.  The check for duplicates works much better than the simple search function.

Comment: @Chenmunka Oh that's a great idea, *thanks!* Yes I have found results sometimes remarkable, it pulls up my previously posted and forgotten question as soon as I start typing a few words, it's freaked me out on occasion! It's not working this time but it's probably because the words are almost orthogonal to what I'm trying somehow.

Answer (score 4):

You could add a bookmark, 20 people already did so with this question. Then you'll just have to go to the bookmark tab in your profile to find it. Of course it could get tricky if you had hundreds of bookmarks, but you can sort them by vote, and since this question is at `+35`, it would probably show near the top. Also, once in your bookmarks you could narrow the search down by adding `inbookmarks:mine` to the search query.

Edit: There is actually an advanced [search option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) to find community wiki posts. The boolean `wiki` can be set to `wiki:1`, `wiki:yes` or `wiki:true` to return only community wiki posts.

Comment: Yes this works nicely, cuz it's 21 now :-)

Answer (score 2):

I clicked the "tags" tab, looked up "resource", which auto-completed "resource-request".  Then I sorted by vote-count and the question popped to the top!  However, this is probably just a partial answer, since I don't know how to make this question more findable/accessible. In fact, I am not even sure how to look at just our community wiki info.

[image]

Comment: The boolean `wiki` can be used to limit the search to community posts only.